# How to use Trees.isAccessible() for primitive datatypes in Java Compiler API / How to convert TypeMirror to DeclaredType

Tags: java, java-compiler-api, scopes

I am trying to analyze .java-files using the Java Compiler API. My current problem is to find out, whether a given variable, method or class is known at a specific scope in the program (with scope I mean a scope as it is defined in the Java Compiler API itself, see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/tree/Scope.html).

The Trees class of the Java Compiler API (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/util/Trees.html) has a utility method to do that: isAccessible. This method gets a Scope and the target node as well as its declared type and returns true, if the target node is known in the given scope.

Unfortunately I do not know, how to create this DeclaredType-object (I can only write class names from now on and post no more hyperlinks because of stackoverflows spam prevention: javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType). I can ask the target Node for its type (javax.lang.model.element.Element [the asType()-method]) but that returns a TypeMirror-instance, not a DeclaredType.

Currently i use these two lines of code:

```
final DeclaredType nodeType = (DeclaredType) nodeTypeMirror;
isAccessible = referenceCompTree.isAccessible(referenceScope, nodeElement, nodeType);
```

where "referenceCompTree" is the Trees-instance for the current program, referenceScope is the Scope in question, nodeElement is the node in question and nodeType ... well, that should be the DeclaredType of the node in question.

This direct typecast approach works fine for one case, which is the node of a class (I assume this works because a node declares its own type and therefore its typeMirror is equivalent to its own type). But it does definitely not work for variables with primitive types (as stated in the header) and I am not sure whether it works for variables at all.

**Does anyone know either**

1. **how to use the isAccessible-method of Trees for primitive types, or more specifically: How to generally convert a TypeMirror instance to a DeclaredType instance? or**
2. **how to get the information I want (if a variable, class or method is known in a given scope) without using isAccessible?**

*Appendix:*

I did do further research on both questions and want to present to you some of the things I found out:

1. There is a utility-class called Types (javax.lang.model.util.Types). An instance of types can be acquired using the standard Java Compiler API classes (in this case: com.sun.source.util.JavaTask). This object has a method (getDeclaredType) that returns a DeclaredType instance for a given TypeElement and some TypeMirrors. But this method does not work for me either because it throws an error stating that I used to few input arguments. I suppose this method has the sole purpose of returning a DeclaredType instance for a given raw class and some type parameters (e.g. to create the DeclaredType-instance for HashMap you would use this method with the typeElement for HashMap and two typeMirrors for String). Obviously this is not what I intend to do.
2. I tried to program a workaround by determining manually if a variable, class or method is known in a given scope by looking up its respective modifiers and searching through the scope tree, but I am not convinced by this approach for two main reasons: I am not sure whether I got all the special cases of Javas scope construction right in my search algorithm and secondly this seems awfully unnecessary because I try to reimplement something that (seemingly) is already there and that the Java Compiler does all the time. Hell, even my NetBeans tells me all the time if a given variable, method or class is known in my current scope. So there has to be some way.

Comment: To conclude this: I used the workaround mentioned in the appendix (2) now and it seems to work well enough until now. So if you have the same problem: Try reimplementing the scope management yourself.